# Is it possible to add errors to an ActiveRecord object without associating them with a particular attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If you need to code a considerably complex validation, the error sometimes doesnt lie in a particular attribute, but in a combination of several of them.

For example, if i want to validate that a the time period between :start_date and :end_date doesnt contain any sunday, the error doesnt belong specifically to either of those fields, but  the Errors add method requires to specify it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

```
# Your Model.rb
validate :my_own_validation_method

...

private

def my_own_validation_method
    if there_is_no_sunday_in_the_range
        self.errors[:base] << "You must have a Sunday in the time range!"
    end
end
```

Basically, you can add your own complex validations to a model, and when you see that something erroneous has happened, you can add an error string in the array of errors.

Comment: Perfect, this is just what I needed. Couldnt find it in the docs

Comment: Well normally you can add an error to a specific attribute. For example, if you had a `User` model that had an `age` attribute, you might want to add an error for that attribute, so you would write `self.errors[:age] << "cannot be less than 0"` which will make an error like "Age cannot be less than 0". But if the error isn't about any specific attribute, you can add it to the base, i.e to the model itself. So `self.errors[:base] << "Everything is wrong!"` makes the error message "Everything is wrong!"; it's not connected to any specific attribute.

Comment: This approach is not valid for Rails 7
`@object.errors.add(:attr, 'error message')` shall be used instead

Answer (score 9):

```
model_instance.errors[:base] << "msg"
```

Answer (score 9):

The answers above are outdated.  For Rails 5 and higher you need to call the [ActiveModel::Errors add](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-add) method with `:base` as the first parameter.  See the example below.

```
model_instance.errors.add(
  :base, 
  :name_or_email_blank, 
  message: "either name or email must be present"
)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `errors[:base]` to add general errors that aren't specifically tied to one attribute - [rails guide link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#errors-base).

Answer (score 1):

You can actually name the hash key whatever you'd like:

```
instance.errors[:case_of_the_sundays] << "Error, son."
```

Just a little more descriptive.

Answer (score -1):

Update:
message array in order to add an error is deprecated.

Now we do something like that.

```
self.errors.add(:some_key, "Some Error!")
```

Comment: from Rails 6.1 (https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/32313)